# c, b = a, c + 1でNameError例外が送出される理由は？

Tags: python

> Problem 6: What will be the output of the following program.

```
a, b = 2, 3
c, b = a, c + 1
print a, b, c
```

こちらを実行しようとすると。。。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

と出てきます。

```
c = a
```

としているにもかかわらずなので、よく理解が出来ません。

Comment: タイトルを質問内容に合わせて具体化しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python の言語リファレンスの[評価順序の項](http://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)によれば、

> Python は、式を左から右へと順に評価します。ただし、代入式を評価するときは、代入演算子の右側項が左側項よりも先に評価されます。

とありますので、代入演算子の右辺の式が全て計算されてから、左辺に代入されます。リンク先には

```
expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
```

という例があります (expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4 の順に計算される)。

Answer (score 7):

まずはじめに`a, c + 1`が計算され、その結果が`c, b` に代入されるためです。

Comment: >>> a, b = 2, 3
>>> c = a
>>> b = c + 1
>>> print a, b, c
2 3 2

とすればできましたが、この最終行を得るためには前出の2行目をどのように改善すればよろしかったでしょうか？今ひとつご教示願います。

Comment: 書かれてらっしゃるとおりの方法でいいと思いますよ。

Answer (score 2):

`NameError`になるのは、まさにそのエラー行に書かれているように、`c`という変数が登場する前に`c + 1`という、`c`の中身を参照する操作を行っているためです。

```
c, b = a, c + 1
```

この行の、`c + 1`を処理する時点で、まだ`c`という変数が定義されていないとPythonコンパイラに解釈されました。*同じ行に書かれているので、どの順番で実行するかはPython言語の仕様とコンパイラの実装次第になります。*

解決法はuser2989353さんご自身が先に試されているとおり、処理を2行に分割し、`c`の初期値の設定を`c + 1`を行う前に実行させるよう、処理の順番を強制するしかありません。

Comment: この回答はなんで評価が下げられているんでしょうね？正しい答えなのに。アゲておきました。